# Spring Controller Request Mapping not working

Tags: spring

Here is my code:

web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Registration Web Service</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/reg/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.magic.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

HomeController:

```
package org.magic.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
                + "<h3>********** Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3>This message is coming from CrunchifyHelloWorld.java **********</div><br><br>";
        return new ModelAndView("index", "message", message);
    }
}
```

Request URL: http://localhost:8080/registration/reg/welcome

Here is my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.magic</groupId>
  <artifactId>registration</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>registration Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>registration</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: please show your stacktrace

Comment: I am a beginner in eclipse. Unable to get any stack trace even when application is in debug mode.

Comment: any error message ?

Comment: No error or exception. Here is my console output:

Comment: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Sep 18, 2016 9:37:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1285 ms
Sep 18, 2016 9:37:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2994 ms

Comment: Doesn't look like a request mapping error.  That's for sure

Comment: Added my POM file as well.

Comment: I would go for another spring tutorial.  The one from tutorialspoint.com works fine.

Comment: check the spring startup log if the URL mapping is registered. Also enable debug level logging for the spring MVC package and you can see what is happening when you try to navigate to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to be mentioned:

First you are using `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver` which needs a property called `viewClass`. So you either define it or use a different view resolver implementation, such as `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver`. More info about this is given here: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/74825-urlbasedviewresolver

Btw. I could see it in the stacktrace like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'viewClass' is required
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.initApplicationContext(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:430)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:120)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:76)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:74)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:121)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:97)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ... 64 more
```

If you keep on using the `UrlBasedViewResolver` your dispatcher-servlet.xml So basically should look like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.magic.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Further I saw that you're expecting an application context `/registration`. Please double-check whether you've configured it or not. I was able to run your application without application context by simply calling http://localhost:8080/reg/welcome

Hope it helps. Please let me know if you got it up and running!